# Spherical Harmonic Plotting

Tags: graphics, demonstrations

I have tried to plot on the surface of a sphere the spherical harmonic functions by closely following this demonstration

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NodalDomainsOfSphericalHarmonics/

I've copied the script from the picture available from the site as closely as I could, but when I run it the image doesn't change when I change the Manipulate settings.

```
    Manipulate[If[Abs[m] > l, m = Sign[m] l]; 
 coloredSphere[l, m, reim, ControlActive[30, pp]],
 {{reim, Re, "view"}, {Re -> "real", Im -> "imaginary"}},
 {{l, 6, "l"}, 0, 12, 1},
 {{m, 3, "m"}, -l, l, 1},
 {{pp, 40, "points"}, 3, 50, 1},
 Initialization :>
  {makeColoredSphereGraphicsComplex[points_, normals_, colors_] :=
    Module[{lOuter = Length[points], lInner = Length[points[[1]]]},
     GraphicsComplex[Flatten[N[points], 1], {EdgeForm[],
       GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[Flatten[#, 1] &@

           Table[{i lInner + j, 
             i lInner + j + 1, (i + 1) lInner + j + 
              1, (i + 1) lInner + j}, {i, 0, lOuter - 2}, {j, 
             lInner - 1}]]}]},
      VertexNormals -> Flatten[N[normals], 1],
      VertexColors -> Flatten[N[normals], 1]]
     ];
   spherePoints[n_] := spherePoints[n] =
     Module[{\[Psi]s = 2. Pi (Range[0, 2 n]/(2 n)), \[Phi]s = 
        1. Pi (Range[0, n]/n)},
      c\[Psi]s = Cos[\[Psi]s]; s\[Psi]s = Sin[\[Psi]s];
      c\[Phi]s = Cos[\[Phi]s]; s\[Phi]s = Sin[\[Phi]s];
      \[Psi]ones = Table[1., {k, 0, 2 n}];
      xs = Outer[Times, c\[Psi]s, s\[Phi]s];
      ys = Outer[Times, s\[Psi]s, s\[Phi]s];
      zs = Outer[Times, \[Psi]ones, c\[Phi]s];
      Transpose[{xs, ys, zs}, {3, 1, 2}]
      ];
   colors[n_, {l_, m_}, reim_] := colors[n, {l, m}, reim] =
     Module[{\[Psi]s = 2. Pi Range[0, 2 n]/(2 n), \[Phi]s = 
        1. Pi Range[0, n]/n, \[Psi]L, \[Phi]L, 
       hueData, \[CapitalDelta]h},
      \[Psi]L = reim[Exp[I m \[Psi]s]];
      \[Phi]L = LegendreP[l, m, Cos[\[Phi]s]];
      hueData = Outer[Times, \[Psi]L, \[Phi]L];
      \[CapitalDelta]h = 
       If[Max[hueData] == Min[hueData], 1, 
        Max[hueData] - Min[hueData]];
      Map[Hue, 0.8 (hueData - Min[hueData])/\[CapitalDelta]h, {2}]
      ];
   coloredSphere[l_, m_, reim_, pp_] :=
    Graphics3D[
     makeColoredSphereGraphicsComplex[spherePoints[pp], 
      spherePoints[pp], colors[pp, {l, m}, reim]], Boxed -> False, 
     ImageSize -> {400, 350}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
     ViewAngle -> \[Pi]/10];}]
```

I went through the script thinking something was wrong but I simply cannot understand what's going on with the GraphicsComplex function.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Thank you, that worked beautifully.  If you write it as an answer I'll select it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `VertexNormals -> Flatten[N[normals], 1]` by `VertexColors -> Flatten[colors, 1]` in `makeColoredSphereGraphicsComplex`.